# Good references for setting up Nginx : for app running in Wildfly18(+Adapter) talking to local Keycloak9(Wildfly) on Linux (Ubuntu)

Tags: keycloak

I am looking for good references for setting up Nginx: for a Java (J8EE) app running in Wildfly18(+Adapter)[Set up as service] talking to local Keycloak9(Wildfly)[Set up as service] on Linux (Ubuntu).

This will be a simple setup (No clustering etc.) and can even use LetsEncrypt if required.

Works locally on W10; and have set up mostly on an ubuntu server; but serve, now being remote, is making things more awkward.

Any references greatly received.

Answer (score 0):

I have done the NGINX (using letsencrypt) and posted it here.

There was a realy horrid problem then with "invalid redirect uri" problem and this post also have the "solution" to that.

See:
[Moving to https in keycloak using nginx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60496274/moving-to-https-in-keycloak-using-nginx/60513992#60513992)